# How to select certain pieces of a string in Python 3?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am trying to select 2 letters from a string by using a sliding window. My code works but I am not getting the proper output. This is my code:

```
s = "aaabccddd"
b = [s[i:i + 2] for i in range(len(s) - 2)]
print(b)
```

The output from my code is:

```
['aa', 'aa', 'ab', 'bc', 'cc', 'cd', 'dd']
```

But the ouput should be like this:

```
['aa','ab','cc', 'dd', 'd']
```

How can i fix my code and get the desired ouput?

Comment: You can use this : `[s[i:i+2] for i,j in enumerate(s) if i % 2 ==0]`

Comment: you can generalize it for any `size` you want like this: `[s[i:i+size] for i in range(0, len(s), size)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to skip the right amount of bytes when you use `range()` like this: `range(0, len(s) - 2, 2)` , otherwise you would get two characters for every original character.

you can generalize this to any size of chunk you want:

```
def split_string(s, size):
    return [s[i:i+size] for i in range(0, len(s), size)]
```